# R average values without NA

Tags: r, dataframe, average

My problem is explained in the attached picture (link).

[image: link image description problem]

I have tried following codes without result:

```
df[paste0("combined_", df_of_column_names)] <- lapply(df, ave, na.rm =TRUE, df[["index Z"]])
```

which does not return an average value where there are NAs present

```
df[paste0("combined_", df_of_column_names)] <- lapply(df, ave(FUN=function(x) mean(x, na.rm=T)), df[["index Z"]])
```

which gives the error:

> Error in FUN(x) : argument "x" is missing, with no default

Can somebody help me with this? Many thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, add some data not as image, to use in R and help you.

Comment: Are you restricted to base R? There are easier ways to do this with R libraries.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @s_t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using base R I was able to get this to work on a simple case similar to yours.

```
attach(warpbreaks)
wool[5] <- NA
df <- data.frame(wool = wool, break = breaks)
df <- cbind(df, df$wool)

df
   wool breaks breaks.1
1     A     26       26
2     A     30       30
3     A     54       54
4     A     25       25
5     A     NA       NA
6     A     52       52
...

lapply(df[,-1], function(x) ave(x, df[,1], FUN = function(x) mean(x, na.rm=TRUE)))

$breaks
 [1] 29.53846 29.53846 29.53846 29.53846 29.53846 29.53846 29.53846 29.53846
 [9] 29.53846 29.53846 29.53846 29.53846 29.53846 29.53846 29.53846 29.53846
[17] 29.53846 29.53846 29.53846 29.53846 29.53846 29.53846 29.53846 29.53846
[25] 29.53846 29.53846 29.53846 25.25926 25.25926 25.25926 25.25926 25.25926
[33] 25.25926 25.25926 25.25926 25.25926 25.25926 25.25926 25.25926 25.25926
[41] 25.25926 25.25926 25.25926 25.25926 25.25926 25.25926 25.25926 25.25926
[49] 25.25926 25.25926 25.25926 25.25926 25.25926 25.25926

$breaks.1
 [1] 29.53846 29.53846 29.53846 29.53846 29.53846 29.53846 29.53846 29.53846
 [9] 29.53846 29.53846 29.53846 29.53846 29.53846 29.53846 29.53846 29.53846
[17] 29.53846 29.53846 29.53846 29.53846 29.53846 29.53846 29.53846 29.53846
[25] 29.53846 29.53846 29.53846 25.25926 25.25926 25.25926 25.25926 25.25926
[33] 25.25926 25.25926 25.25926 25.25926 25.25926 25.25926 25.25926 25.25926
[41] 25.25926 25.25926 25.25926 25.25926 25.25926 25.25926 25.25926 25.25926
[49] 25.25926 25.25926 25.25926 25.25926 25.25926 25.25926
```

Answer (score 0):

Without a reproducible example it is hard to give a relevant answer but  try out:

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- df %>% # df is your data frame
        group_by(`index Z`) %>% 
        summarise_all(.funs = mean, na.rm = TRUE) 
# expected output
left_join(df1[, 1], df2, by = `index Z`)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using library dplyr. Check this example:

```
df1 %>% group_by(index) %>%
  summarise(modreturn1 = mean(return1,na.rm = T), modreturn2 = mean(return2,na.rm = T))
```

It will return a table summarizing the first two variables into their means (excluding `NA`'s).
Now, if you really want as many rows as your original dataset:
First, save the above query to a variable named `resumen`, then:

```
merge(df1[,"index"],resumen,all.x = T)
```

You are welcome :)

Comment: Hey Jorge,
For answers with written code please utilize the code sections (short key: Mark code press ctrl + K) for easier reading. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Similar answer as ANG but using data.table

```
library(data.table)
df <- setDT(df)
df2 <- df[,lapply(.SD,mean), by = `index Z`]
df2[df, on = `index Z`]
```